# create a post with pre-defined categories

Tags: laravel

I have a table for posts and a table for categories. But its not possible to create new categories they should already exist in the database and is not possible to change them. DO you know how to structure this logic properly on laravel?

Also when a post is created it should have a maximum of 3 categories and a published date. Do you know how to do that validation in laravel, of dates and the maximum of 3 categories when a post is created? I have this validation for now:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
           ‘post_name’ => 'required|max:255',
           ‘post_categories’ => 'required',
            ‘post_date' => 'required',

        ]);
```

Relevant code for this context:

**// Category Model:**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post’);
    }
}
```

**// Post model**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

}
```

**Migration Post:**

```
class CreatePost extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create(‘posts’, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string(‘name’);
            …
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**Migration Category:**

```
<?php

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

**// post controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view(‘app.createPost’);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());

        $this->validate($request, [
           ‘post_name’ => 'required|max:255',
           ‘post_categories’ => 'required',
            ‘post_date' => 'required',

        ]);
}
```

Comment: How does `post_categories` look like in the request? is an array?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its a select option using the select2 plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [between](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-between) rule

```
'post_categories' => 'required|array|between:1,3'
```

And for the first question, use [firstOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

```
foreach($request->post_categories as $categoryName){

   $category= App\Category::firstOrCreate(['name' => $categoryName]);

  $post->categories->attach($category->id);

}
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe i didnt explain well. Its not possible to create new categories, wthen the user create a new post he needs to select between 1 and 3 categories that appear in a select menu, but that categories should be available on the select menu when the user access the create new post page, the user cannot introduce any category, so maybe the firstOrCreate method is not for that?

Comment: But so for the first question, its only necessary insert in the db the categories? Its not necessary anything in the model or something?